# Altair Grouped Bar Chart With Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart, stock, altair

I have this DataFrame called `table`:

```
    TERM                        Bitcoin       S&P500    Real Estate Gold
0   High-Inflation/ Short term  3097.94       -3700.78  761.23      6512.71
1   High-Inflation/ Mid term    —             -3080.01  -8434.66    3242.40
2   High-Inflation/ Long term   —             -2089.25  -9117.96    8174.43
3   Low-Inflation/ Short term   780200.00     -273.71   1824.72     2214.51
4   Low-Inflation/ Mid term     21013600.00   5331.40   35810.58    -2879.37
5   Low-Inflation/ Long term    978017143.00. 15045.41  35895.81    861.90
```

And I want to make a grouped (or stacked) bar chart that distinguishes return on investments for each of these assets based on the `TERM` column. I have tried this:

```
alt.Chart(table).transform_fold(
    ["Bitcoin", "S&P500", "Real Estate", "Gold"], as_=["key", "value"]
).mark_bar().encode(
        x="key:N",
        y="value:Q",
        color="key:N",
        column="TERM",
    )
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work fine, the only problem is that the values are at such vastly different scales that only the largest shows up on a linear scale. You can address this by switching to a `symlog` scale. For example:

```python
import pandas as pd
import io
import altair as alt

table = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""\
row    TERM                        Bitcoin       S&P500   "Real Estate" Gold
0   "High-Inflation/ Short term"  3097.94       -3700.78  761.23      6512.71
1   "High-Inflation/ Mid term"    —             -3080.01  -8434.66    3242.40
2   "High-Inflation/ Long term"   —             -2089.25  -9117.96    8174.43
3   "Low-Inflation/ Short term"   780200.00     -273.71   1824.72     2214.51
4   "Low-Inflation/ Mid term"     21013600.00   5331.40   35810.58    -2879.37
5   "Low-Inflation/ Long term"    978017143.00. 15045.41  35895.81    861.90
"""), delim_whitespace=True)

alt.Chart(table).transform_fold(
    ["Bitcoin", "S&P500", "Real Estate", "Gold"], as_=["key", "value"]
).mark_bar().encode(
    x="key:N",
    y=alt.Y("value:Q", scale=alt.Scale(type='symlog')),
    color="key:N",
    column="TERM",
)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks Jake! Do you know how to make the labels at the top less smushed, and how to remove the `key` label from the x-axis of all the graphs?

Comment: Sure, but that's an entirely different question.

Comment: I just asked that question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/70841887/15975987